# Angular4 async pipe with ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've this `ngFor` in my component:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
     {{item}}
    </li>
```

Here is my component code:

```
this.items$ = Observable.of(true)
    .flatMap((shouldPresentNumbers) => {
      if(shouldPresentNumbers)
         return  Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(1,2,3,4,5));
    });
```

My goal is to render items asynchronically. Means that I need that `items$` would get an object of type `Observable<Array<any>>`.
Unfortunately, after running the code above i'm gettin only a single observable to `items$` (Observable of the last value -> 5).

How can I return an Observable of [1,2,3,4,5] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay let's discuss this construction:

```
Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(1,2,3,4,5))
```

`Observable.of()` produces one `Observable` which emits 5 items in a row. `fork-join` waits until it completes and then returns the last item which is 5. What you need is an `Observable` with an array of 5 items:

```
Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
```

So, you can simplify your code this way:

```
this.items$ = Observable.of(true)
    .flatMap((shouldPresentNumbers) => Observable.of(shouldPresentNumbers ? [1,2,3,4,5] : []));
```

[Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/9Ze25RzLlmUeRYC9z0CL/)

Comment: and suppose I have no control on Observable.of (1,2,3,4,5) ? How can I convert it to Observable.of ([1,2,3,4,5]) programatically?

Comment: Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toArray()

Comment: toArray would make an observable that would emit the entire array. values would not be emitted one by one. is it correct?

Comment: Correct, It waits until an observable completes then emits all its values as a single array